# iOS - NSFileHandle availableData hangs only when app is run manually on device

Tags: ios, stdout, nsfilehandle

I have a file handle set up to read the contents of stdout, and when I try to pull the data out of it using availableData it hangs, but only when the app is run manually on my device.  When I run the app on my device through Xcode or on the simulator, it pulls the data out as expected and the rest of my code works perfectly.  Any ideas what is happening?  My code is below:

```
int pipefd[2];                
pipe(pipefd);
dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
close(pipefd[1]);

NSFileHandle *stdoutReader = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:pipefd[0]];

// this method writes output to stout
int result = [self createOutput:string1:string2];

// code hangs on this next line when app is run manually on device)
NSData *stdoutData = [stdoutReader availableData];
```

I am wondering if on my device, the createOutput method runs more slowly and so by the time I try to get data out of stdout there isn't any yet?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like iOS 5.1 doesn't allow writing to stdout anymore.  For anyone interested in reading more, here's an informative blog post: http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/ios-5-1-vs-stdout/